# React: Environment Specific Config on Production Builds

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app, dotenv

My company uses the three standard environments: Development, Test, and Production. My create-react-app based application is hosted as a content item within our CMS, so to get it into any environment, I need to run the `npm run build` command.

I've created a file, config.js, which exports a different configuration object based on variables in `process.env`, but the default behavior here has the limitation that `npm run build` is always considered production. This makes sense, I just need different behavior.

What I'd like to do is run a script like `npm run build:dev`, etc, which sets a process.env variable that I can switch on. Essentially I need to create an npm script that sets a `dotenv` variable, then calls `npm run build`.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use cross-env package (from npm) to define a environment variable.

Just install the package:

```
npm install --save-dev cross-env
```

And create your custom script hwere do you define your variable, for example:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --config build/webpack.config.js"
  }
}
```

It worked like a charm on my projects.

More information here [cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env)